# Asp.net core 3.0 razor pages - creating a dynamic grid from a list

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-3.0

On my razor page I have a grid of two columns generated as below:

```
                    @foreach (var row in Model.MyList
                        .Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
                        .GroupBy(_ => _.index / 2, _ => _.item)
                        )
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            @foreach (var item in row)
                            {

                                <div class="col">
                                //stuff
                                </div>
                            }
                         }
```

The problem is that this is not dynamic and needs to change if the page is resized.

I cannot think how to do this in js, especially since I don't want the last item to take up all the space if there is an odd number of items.

Comment: Resizing is handled by CSS rules, not Razor code or Javascript. The ASP.NET Core  templates use Bootstrap whose styles *already* take care of resizing and adopting to different devices

Comment: As I want the default to be 2 objects per column how to I go about coding this? I may have used the approach originally but if there was an odd number of items the last one was a different size because it used the whole width of the row.